# SugarCRM Custom Theme 6.5.13

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to create a custom theme for my SugarCRM CE 6.5.13 setup.

I've tried everything I can find. I copied the Sugar5 theme folder to the custom/themes/folder and renamed it Sugar-Custom.
I edited the themedef.php file. The theme shows up in my theme selector in the admin panel.

I went in and changed every instance of a color in the css/style.css file, just to make sure I can get that working, but that didn't work.

I did a Repair/Rebuild and I deleted my cache/themes/ files.
I cleared my browser cache.

But, when I do an inspect element (using Chrome) it shows its still pulling the css files from the Sugar5 theme folder. How is that possible if I selected the custom theme? I must be doing something wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the theme as your default theme in your personal settings. The global setting doesn't override the user settings. the global setting only works for new users.